# Sampling down - java android - matlab.

Tags: java, android, arrays, matlab, android-activity

So here is trick of today. am reading from text file array of string numbers. It is about more than 4000 numbers - base on my pressure sensor. I have traced my code fine, and then I did simple algorithm to find all the max. peaks in that array. I have did the same algorithm in matlab and I skipped every 5 element by **If(i%5==0){//do find the peak when it is greater than 0 or not** It works very well in matlab, I did find the the local maximal of all the peaks. (but not the unwanted peaks because of the noise - I don't need them).  I also filtered the array by saying **if (dataOfArray>170){//do find every peak above 170.** However, I have got 11 peaks in matlab while I have got 22 peaks in java android. Note the code is same if there is smthg wrong I didn't notice. Like matlab indexing starts from 1 while java starts from 0. I hope someone can tell why my java code is not performing as the matlab. I have to get the same. hopefully.

```
 clear all
 close all
 clc
 x=load('string.txt');
 tmax=(length(x)-1)/100;
 t1_n=0:0.05:tmax;
 x4 = x(1:5:end);
 x1_n_ref=0;
 k=0;
 for i=1:length(t1_n)
     if x4(i)>170
        if x1_n_ref-x4(i)<0
           x1_n_ref=x4(i);
           alpha=1;
    elseif alpha==1 && x1_n_ref-x4(i)>0
           k=k+1;
           peak(k)=x1_n_ref;
           peak_time(k)=t1_n(i-1);
           alpha=2;
    else

       end
   else
    x1_n_ref=0;
   end

   end

  figure(1)
  hold on
  plot(t1_n,x4,'b');



 //Java code.



 //Read data.
    Recall = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Recall);
    Recall.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       StringBuilder stringBuilder =  new StringBuilder();;
        boolean bTt = false;
        String line = null;
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //readTextFile(this, R.raw.books);

            try {
                FileInputStream fIn = new FileInputStream(file);
                BufferedReader bufferedreader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fIn));
                while ((line = bufferedreader.readLine()) != null) {
                   stringBuilder.append(line).append(" ");
                 stringBuilder.length();
                   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Data_Read_number:  " + stringBuilder.capacity(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                   // Log.i(TAG, "Capacity" + stringBuilder.capacity());
                }
                bufferedreader.close();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            String Adata = String.valueOf(stringBuilder);
            // find the peaks

            String dataArray[];
            dataArray = Adata.split("\\s+");
            List String_TO_List = new ArrayList<Float>();
            boolean bstart = false;
            int lastLength = dataArray.length -1;
            for(int i=0;i<lastLength;i++){
                float dataOfArray =  Float.parseFloat(dataArray[i]);
                if (dataOfArray>170){
                    bstart = true;
                }else {
                    bstart = false;
                }
                if (bstart){
                    //take String i from dataArray, convert it to a float with Float.parseFloat, then add it to your list
                    String_TO_List.add(dataOfArray);
                }

            }
            List<Integer> List_Of_Peaks = findPeaks(String_TO_List);
            // List a = findPeaks(aa);
            Log.i(TAG,"Peaks"+ List_Of_Peaks);
        //    DataAlert alert = new DataAlert();
          //  alert.show(getFragmentManager(), "DataAlert");
           // Peaks_value.setText(a.toString());
           // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                          //  "Number of peaks:" + List_Of_Peaks, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Peaks_num.setText(String.valueOf(List_Of_Peaks));

        }

    });

}//end OnCreate().


public static ArrayList<Float> findPeaks(List<Float> points)
{
    if (points== null || points.size() < 1)
        return null;

    ArrayList<Float> peaks = new ArrayList<Float>();
    float x1_n_ref = 0;
    int alpha = 0;
    int size = points.size();
    for (int i = 0; i <size ; i++) {
        float IndexValues = points.get(i);
        if(i%5 == 0 ){
            if (x1_n_ref - IndexValues < 0) {
                x1_n_ref = points.get(i);
                alpha = 1;
            } else if (alpha == 1 && x1_n_ref - points.get(i) > 0) {
                peaks.add(x1_n_ref);
                alpha = 0;
            }else {
                x1_n_ref = 0;

            }
      }

    }

    return peaks;
}
```

Comment: You are doing things in a different order. In your matlab code you mod by 5 and then check if greater than 170. In you Java code you check if greater than 170 then mod by 5.

Comment: Same thing, I did try that either.